# Failed to allocate gateway with docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to execute the [tutorial from the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/). It works fine except with Services.

When I start 5 instances of the container (with docker stack command), the containers are not starting and I get this error:

> "failed to allocate gateway"

```
$ docker stack ps getstartedlab

ID            NAME                     IMAGE                                  NODE                       DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE            ERROR                             PORTS
imb6vgifjvq7  getstartedlab_web.1      seb/docker-whale:1.1  ns3553081.ip-XXX-YYY-ZZZ.eu  Ready          Rejected 4 seconds ago   "failed to allocate gateway (1…"  
ulm1tqdhzikd   \_ getstartedlab_web.1  seb/docker-whale:1.1  ns3553081.ip-XXX-YYY-ZZZ.eu  Shutdown       Rejected 9 seconds ago   "failed to allocate gateway (1…"  
...
```

The docker-compose.yml contains

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: seb/docker-whale:1.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

to start containers I'm using the command:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
```

I can start without any issue one instance of the container with the command:

```
$ docker run -p 80:80 seb/docker-whale:1.1
```

Any idea why it's not working? How can I get more details on the error?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have done the same tests on my Mac running Sierra (10.12.5) and it works fine.

I believe the issue is related to the Linux machine? It's running with:
DISTRIB_ID=Debian
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8
DISTRIB_CODENAME=
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian

Linux 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 x86_64

Comment: The first time I ran it, it worked, the second time, I got the same error. So I presume 'something' is still running, but I have no idea what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from a beginner: Same here (version 1.13.1), the message vanished when I changed ports "80:80" to "8080:80". Port 80 was used by the host of the docker machine.